# QEMU installation on Windows 8.1

Tags: arm, installation, windows-8.1, qemu

It's been quite a while trying to get qemu installed and working on my Windows 8.1 machine. I know that it works best on Linux, but I want to give it a try to have it working on Windows first.

I have tried more than a build.

1. I have tried installing several versions from this site: http://lassauge.free.fr/qemu/
   the versions that I have tried are 1.5.3 and 1.6.0 (all zip files). It's kinda working but I find its behavior to be strange though. I have tried to run hello world program using qemu-system-arm with the following command:

   qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -m 128M -nographic -kernel test.bin

   When I run this command, qemu starts (you can view that the process takes some attention from the processor from the task manager; since the qemu emulator takes about 30% of the processing power) but doesn't end!! It's like it's stuck within an infinite loop or so. The test.bin is test on another qemu (on Linux Ubuntu) and it's working just fine. By working fine I mean "Hello world" is displayed on the terminal.
   **Note** that I found *stdout.txt* file generated after running the previous command. The file contains "Hello world" though. Another file is generated named *stderr.txt* but it contains nothing.
2. I have tried another build: http://homepage3.nifty.com/takeda-toshiya/. version 0.13. A *stderr.txt* file is generated stating that

> chardev: backend "stdio" not found

I have made some search and couldn't find any answer.

so any help with this topic?

Answer (score 1):

I have found [this page](http://xathrya.web.id/blog/2013/03/12/qemu-on-windows/) explains clearly what's going on concerning qemu on Windows. From all of the builds and versions for every build, I have found that [this one](http://lassauge.free.fr/qemu/release/Qemu-1.5.3-windows.zip) is the working one. The mentioned build is from [this page](http://lassauge.free.fr/qemu/). Congratz!! You now have a working version of qemu on your Windows machine.

**Note**: The mentioned version is working just fine. However, it doesn't work with zynq boards and I have no idea why. But it works well with versatile board.